# How does NSNotificationQueue coalesce senders?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotifications

When you specify `NSNotificationCoalescingOnSender` as you post a notification via `NSNotificationQueue`, how does it consider two senders being "equal" ? Is it via a simple pointer equality (e.g. using `==`) or does equality is determined by the `isEqual` method?

Reason being that I would like to use `NSNumber` objects as senders and would like notifications to be coalesced by two "senders" being the same number. That is, if there is a notification with name "myNotification" and sender "123" posted in one part of the app and another part posts the same notification name and "123" as the sender (although they're likely to be distinct objects instances as the sender), I'd like those to be coalesced into one notification.

The background is that the number represents a server-side unique identifier for a record and whenever one part of the app needs to refresh an object, it will post a notification with the server-side ID as the sender. Thus if the same ID is posted multiple times, there will only be one notification and one request to the server.